# How can I style an ASP.NET Radio List so that the label appears before the input?

Tags: asp.net, css

I want to style an ASP.NET RadioList so that the list is horizontally oriented, with two rows, the first of labels, and the second of inputs, for example:

A    B    C    D
o    o    o    o

Comment: If the labels have more than three characters, that will be very hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the radio list text value to empty (that is "")
Right above your radio list create labels that correspond to each
radio list button.

Similiar to this question [vb.net checkbox label position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658434/vb-net-checkbox-label-position/4658506#4658506)

Answer (score 0):

Use two lists and style them horizontally in your CSS

The CSS:
.answerL 
{
    list-style-type: none;

}
.answerL
{
    display: block;
}